# Group Messaging System PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, message

I want to create a Group Message System in `PHP`, `MySQL`.

So far so Good I have tried to make something like this.

**MYSQL Structure**

```
`groups` table
group_id | Title | 

`group_msg` table
msg_id| sender_id | group_id | msg | time
```

How can i implement a `seen` System in my group messaging. If a message is seen by a user then its `user_id` will be stored. If i am creating a column `seen` then it can contain only one `user_id`. Is there any way i can solve this ?

**P.S:** Are using primary AI column `msg_id` in the table `group_msg` is necessary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a "seen" table with column 
msg_id| receiver_id

Comment: I feel this is better solution compared to keeping comma separated receiver id in group_msg table